# How to add Listpicker to textbox in LiveCode

Tags: livecode

I want to add a list picker in Live code.When a user click on the Textbox the list picker should open with list of items.How can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that your text field must be locked in order to send a "mouseUp" message, if that is how you want to show the combo box that Monte suggested. There are other ways around this, if you still want to be able to type into that field. Write back with your exact needs.

The combo box is useful because you can type right into it. If you only want options that will load data into an existing field, a popup or pulldown might be something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

On the left side of the tool palette about the middle is a style of button called a combo box. I think that's what you want.